# Get All parents elements based on where condition of the last element

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables with one to many relation.

First table is `status`:

```
| id | product_id | status | created_at          |
|----|------------|--------|---------------------|
| 1  | 1          | 0      | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 1          | 1      | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 3  | 2          | 1      | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4  | 2          | 5      | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 |
```

Relation is

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

Second is `product`:

```
| id | name      |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | product_1 |
| 2  | product_2 |
```

Relation is:

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductStatus');
}
```

I'm trying to get all `product`s where their last `status` is `1`, but I'm getting also `product`s even if it last `status` is `!= 1`  but in history it had `status 1`.

Comment: What query/eloquent query are you using ? What have you tried so far ? Is the `status` table a "history status" because if your answer is no it makes no sense to have 2 or more statuses for the same `product`. Give more info please.

Comment: yes table statue is a history status table

Answer (score 2):

In a non-ideal world you can filter after the fact:

Add a relation:

```
public function latestStatus()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\ProductStatus')->latest();
}
```

This will assume that there relationship is one to one and will therefore only retrieve one status

Then you can do:

```
Product::has('latestStatus')->with('latestStatus')->get()->filter(function (Product $product) {
   return $product->latestStatus->status === 1;
});
```

And I say it's not ideal because this will first get all products and then filter them by latest status.

The challenge is you need nested queries to get what you need in SQL. [The manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins) does describe a solution to this problem using joins which looks like like:

```
$latestStatus = ProductStatus::latest()->take(1);
              
$productsWithLatestStatusOne = Product::joinSub($latestStatus, 'latest_status', function ($join) {
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'latest_status.product_id');
        })
        ->select('products.*')
        ->where('latest_status.status', 1)
        ->get();
```

but of course this uses a subquery join which may be slower.

Comment: This work fine but as you say it not ideal as a solution to get products and than filter them !! 
any idea how to use the reverse relation and getting started from lastStatus to get all products ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware a subquery join with the `$latestStatus` query is a bit unavoidable. The issue isn't eloquent it's just that this is how you would generally solve this problem in SQL as far as I know. However I am in no way an SQL expert so maybe someone who knows the SQL part of it better might correct me

Answer (score 1):

Try [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method

```php
Product::wherehas('status', function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
    $query->where('status', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: you will get products even if his last status is != 1 but in history he had status 1